# Getting multiple values in single Oraclize query

Tags: solidity, oracles

Is it possible to get multiple values in single Oraclize query?

```
contract CheckBet is usingOraclize {

struct Weather {
    uint curr_temperature;
    uint high_temperature;
    uint low_temperature;
}
Weather weather;

/// Event for debugging
event Log(string text);

function CheckBet() {
    get_weather_status();
}

function get_weather_status() payable{
    Log("Oraclize query was sent, waiting for the answer.."); 
    (oraclize_query("URL","json(http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Lond`on,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22).main.temp_min"));
}

//callback function for Oraclize
function __callback(bytes32 _myid, string _result) {
    require (msg.sender == oraclize_cbAddress());
    Log(_result);
    weather.low_temperature = parseInt(_result); 
}
```

In function `get_weather_status`, I'm getting min. temp. I want temp_max, curr_temp too.

Is it possible in single Oraclize query?

**JSON FILE**

```
{
  "main": {
   "temp":280.32,
   "pressure":1012,
   "humidity":81,
   "temp_min":279.15,
   "temp_max":281.15
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same request, there is 2 arguments I want to analyse and there is NO NEED to make 2 HTTP requests. Oraclize docs don't talk about getting multiples values on JSON Parsing https://docs.oraclize.it/#general-concepts-parsing-helpers Did you find a solution ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23295)

Comment: @Bruno I think my solution will work for your situation as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able do this using JSONPATH.

```
(oraclize_query("URL","json(http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Lond`on,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22).main[temp, temp_min, temp_max]"));
```

You can examine the results here http://app.oraclize.it/home/test_query#VVJMKEdFVCk=:anNvbihodHRwOi8vc2FtcGxlcy5vcGVud2VhdGhlcm1hcC5vcmcvZGF0YS8yLjUvd2VhdGhlcj9xPUxvbmRgb24sdWsmYXBwaWQ9YjY5MDdkMjg5ZTEwZDcxNGE2ZTg4YjMwNzYxZmFlMjIpLm1haW5bdGVtcCwgdGVtcF9taW4sIHRlbXBfbWF4XQ==

Answer (score 1):

Quick googling says it might not be trivial. Have a look at https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/issues/10
So, you'd have to parse the result yourself.

P.S. Please accept the answers to your previous questions if you are satisfied with them.

Answer (score 0):

For the **query**: "json(http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Lond`on,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22).main[temp, pressure, humidity, temp_min, temp_max]"

Follow these **rules**: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

[image]